# Android studio crashed in the first run

Tags: crash, android-sqlite

I'm having this error

> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath':
>   Could not find any version that matches
>   com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+.

I slept while the Android studio was downloading gradle ,so My laptop went in sleep mode and stopped everything.

Now I'm getting the error above. I think something is missing from the first run download ,How can i fix it ?

----------EDIT

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

and the second one

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: please add your gradle file

Comment: I will do, But it's a new project @AmanpreetKaur , so it's the default settings

Comment: there is some issue in the gradle that is why it is showing this error

Comment: Alright i have added the gradle, I hope this helps @AmanpreetKaur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Google: This is the stable release of Support Library 28.0.0 and is suitable for use in production. This will be the last feature release under the android.support packaging, and developers are encouraged to migrate to AndroidX.

Refer to https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions

This is why you are getting error on

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+'
```

Either migrate to androidX or you can use

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' 
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

in your gradle

Hope this will help you
Happy Coding